# Python Elasticsearch "No host specified" Error

Tags: python, elasticsearch, url

I’m using Python elasticsearch library to query data from Elasticsearch. When I hardcode the URL it works fine but I’m trying to get the host, username, and password from a config file. I’m using Python ConfigParser to read those parameters.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read(r"C:\configuration.ini")         
Host = config.get("Conn", "Host")
USN = config.get("Conn", "USN")
Pass = config.get("Conn", "Pass")
```

My parameters are Host, USN, and Pass and I’m building the connection string like below:

```
connString =  "['" + Host  + "', http_auth=('" +str(USN) + "', '" + str(Pass) + "')"
client = Elasticsearch(connString) #does not work.
```

But it is giving me “No host specified.” error message. But if I print connString and hardcode that result then it works so it is reading those 3 parameters from the file correctly.

```
connString =  "['" + Host  + "', http_auth=('" +str(USN) + "', '" + str(Pass) + "')"
print(connString) # output: ['https://ElasticsearchURL:9200'], http_auth=('UserName', 'Password')
client=Elasticsearch(['https://ElasticsearchURL:9200'], http_auth=('UserName', 'Password')) #it works
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Posting the code to read the config values and the output of `print(connString)` would increase your chances of a solution.

Comment: `client=Elasticsearch(['https://ElasticsearchURL:9200'], http_auth=('UserName', 'Password'))` This is the correct way. elasticsearch module in python is a wrapper over the http url endpoints